# C program setting port parameters before opening port fails

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I am trying to write c code on a Linux system, where I set the serial port parameters then open the serial port, then I have found out that even though the code compiles and runs, I cannot read and write from that serial port (so the serial port was not opened successfully)!

Code that works (not needed):

```
int fd;
char *portname;
portname = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
struct termios tty;

fd = open(portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTYY | O_SYNC );

memset(&tty,0,sizeof tty);
tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOP;
tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
tty.c_cflag |= CS8;
tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&tty);
```

Code that doesn't work (needed)

```
int fd;
char *portname;
portname = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
struct termios tty;

memset(&tty,0,sizeof tty);
tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOP;
tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
tty.c_cflag |= CS8;
tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&tty);

fd = open(portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTYY | O_SYNC );
```

Solid question: My application sequence requires me to set serial port parameters then open the serial port. Is there a way to do this? if yes, how?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Is your program permitted to open the serial port?

Comment: Since you don't have file descriptor yet you are unable to set any options for the connection. _Why_ does your application require such a design?

Comment: -alk: yes, I just put snippets of my code. -meaning-matters: yes I added myself to the dialout group. -Lukasz: My application requires this design because the program was ported from Windows and had to maintain same structure. Thank you all for your comments.I now understand the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: Removed C++ code noticed by @Alter Mann.
**Update**: Removed zeroing-out the `termios` structure noticed by @sawdust.

In first case you get actual file descriptor `fd` and after use it. In second case you try setting up **uninitialized file descriptor** `fd` (probably `0` if it's declared in global scope) and after get actual value of it.

Below is workaround which works for me:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv [])
{
    struct termios tty;
    const char * portname = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
    const int fd = open (portname, O_RDONLY);
    if (-1 == fd) {
        // Problem...
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (tcgetattr (fd, &tty) < 0) {
        // Problem...
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    cfsetospeed (&tty, (speed_t) B9600);
    cfsetispeed (&tty, (speed_t) B9600);

    tty.c_cflag |= B9600;
    tty.c_cflag |= (tty.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8;
    tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
    tty.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);
    tty.c_cflag |= IGNPAR;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~(CRTSCTS);
    tty.c_cflag &= ~(CSTOPB);
    tty.c_iflag |= IGNBRK;
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
    tty.c_lflag  = 0;
    tty.c_oflag  = 0;

    tcflush (fd, TCIFLUSH);
    if (tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &tty) ) {
        // Problem...
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Zeroing-out the termios structure is poor coding practice.  The preferred/proper method is to use the tcgetattr() syscall.  See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237)